# Setting the Vim background colors

Tags: linux, background, vim, vi

When I try to change the background colors in `.vimrc` or directly in Vim using the command:

```
set background=dark
```

... it doesn't affect my background at all. Neither does the `light` option. However, it looks okay when I run gvim.

Is there a way to change the background in Vim without changing my Konsole settings?

**EDIT** Okay, there is a difference between guifg/guibg and ctermfg/ctermbg. While the GUI accepts lots of different color combinations, cterm allows only few standard ones.

Comment: You can get the terminal to accept a lot of those colours as well. See this page: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/256_colors_in_vim

Answer (score 167, accepted):

As vim's own help on `set background` says, "Setting this option does not change the background color, it tells Vim what the background color looks like. For changing the background color, see |:hi-normal|."

For example

```
:highlight Normal ctermfg=grey ctermbg=darkblue
```

will write in white on blue on your color terminal.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I tried that option before, but it seems that not all colors work, for instance brown and yellow options don't affect my default console background at all.

Comment: that may be b/c of what kind of terminal vim thinks you have.

Comment: Yep, setting up your terminal description properly to make vim happy can be a hassle (I remember epic past battles with early Linux, BSD and other Unix flavors -- nowadays with Mac and Ubuntu it just seems to work, more or less, even across ssh among them, and I don't have to do much vi-editing elsewhere these days).

Comment: How can I add this to my vimrc?

Comment: Also see `:help hl-NonText` for the background colour after the last line of the file.

Comment: @Marin: put exactly the line from the example into your vimrc `:highlight Normal ctermfg=grey ctermbg=darkblue`. Sub in whatever colours you want.

Comment: LPT: don't try to execute `.vimrc` as a shell command just put the line there and be happy

Comment: you can omit the `ctermfg=blah` if you just want to change the background colour

Comment: Putting this in .vimrc does not work for me.

Comment: What does "see |:hi-normal|." mean?

Answer (score 26):

In a terminal emulator like konsole or gnome-terminal, you should to set a 256 color setting for vim.

```
:set  t_Co=256
```

After that you can to change your background.

Comment: You probably want to set that in your Terminal instead: `export TERM='xterm-256color'`.

Answer (score 15):

Try adding

```
set background=dark
```

to your `.gvimrc` too. This work well for me.

Answer (score 6):

Using `set bg=dark` with a white background can produce nearly unreadable text in some syntax highlighting schemes.  Instead, you can change the overall colorscheme to something that looks good in your terminal.  The colorscheme file should set the background attribute for you appropriately.  Also, for more information see:

```
:h color
```

Comment: that actually why I posted my question here. Even dark colorschemes didn't affect my default background color.

Answer (score 2):

## supplement of windows

gvim version: 8.2

location of **.gvimrc**: `%userprofile%/.gvimrc`

```
" .gvimrc
colorscheme darkblue
```

*Which color is allows me to choose?*

Find your install directory and go to the directory of `colors`.
in my case is:
`%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Vim\vim82\colors`

```
blue.vim
darkblue.vim
slate.vim
...
README.txt
```