# How do I change the vim background color (not Normal)

Tags: vim

I've been playing with vim colors, and this is driving me crazy. What is the background color name??? I'm not talking about Normal ctermbg, but whatever's behind that, behind/below your current doc. When I load vim the bg is bright/dark blue, and same underneath my document. Anyone know how to change that??

Comment: Have you seen this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117526/setting-the-vim-background-colors

Answer (score 3):

You can use these commands to obtain a unified red background:

```
:hi Normal  ctermbg=Red
:hi NonText ctermbg=Red
```

But who would want that? ;-)