# Can vim's background color be changed based on the current mode?

Tags: vim

Just to make the title a bit more verbose:

Emphasis is on: **"based on the current mode"**

I would like the background to be one color when in ***normal*** or ***visual*** **mode** and in *another* when I can freely type (***insert*** mode), *automatically* (=> probably autocmd, as mentioned in the solution below).

How can this be done the best way, that works in all modern flavors of vim (especially including terminal rendering)?

Comment: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: Note to any flaggers/closers, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117526/setting-the-vim-background-colors) is not really a duplicate, as this asks for specific colours and probably their overall syntax

Comment: To OP: I think your question is perfectly valid, but you need to add more context and focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check autocmd

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html

for vim 8

```
:autocmd InsertEnter * set bg=light
:autocmd InsertLeave * set bg=dark
```

for vim version 9.0 please check

https://yianwillis.github.io/vimcdoc/doc/autocmd.html#ModeChanged

For the example in the site, you can change to relative numbering when enter visual mode

```
:au ModeChanged [vV\x16]*:* let &l:rnu = mode() =~# '^[vV\x16]'
:au ModeChanged *:[vV\x16]* let &l:rnu = mode() =~# '^[vV\x16]'
:au WinEnter,WinLeave * let &l:rnu = mode() =~# '^[vV\x16]'
```

Comment: It would be great, if you could provide an example for vim 9, as not everybody can read Chinese (?) here.

Comment: When I search for autocmd somehow the solutions for version 9 come up first, I thought it is small thing and I just point out what you can do with version 9. As for the example, I haven’t  quite figure out the syntax, and I am using version 8 on my computer and it’s hard to test on version 9 . I posted one of the examples on the site. Maybe later I will add useful examples but should be untested

Answer (score 0):

#### `highlight` command (temporary)

Use the [`highlight`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:highlight) command:

```
:highlight Normal ctermfg=darkgreen ctermbg=gray
```

This sets the background colour to gray, with dark green text.

Short form:

```
:hi Normal ctermfg=darkgreen ctermbg=gray
```

#### `cterm` colours [`ctermfg`+`ctermbg`]

List of colours [`cterm`]:

```
NR-16   NR-8    COLOR NAME 
0       0       Black
1       4       DarkBlue
2       2       DarkGreen
3       6       DarkCyan
4       1       DarkRed
5       5       DarkMagenta
6       3       Brown, DarkYellow
7       7       LightGray, LightGrey, Gray, Grey
8       0*      DarkGray, DarkGrey
9       4*      Blue, LightBlue
10      2*      Green, LightGreen
11      6*      Cyan, LightCyan
12      1*      Red, LightRed
13      5*      Magenta, LightMagenta
14      3*      Yellow, LightYellow
15      7*      White
```

The number under "NR-16" is used for 16-color terminals ('t_Co'
greater than or equal to 16).  The number under "NR-8" is used for
8-color terminals ('t_Co' less than 16).  The '*' indicates that the
bold attribute is set for ctermfg.  In many 8-color terminals (e.g.,
"linux"), this causes the bright colors to appear.  This doesn't work
for background colors!  Without the '*' the bold attribute is removed.
If you want to set the bold attribute in a different way, put a
"cterm=" argument AFTER the "ctermfg=" or "ctermbg=" argument.  Or use
a number instead of a color name.

Here `*` means 'add 8' so that `Blue` is `12`, `DarkGray` is `8` etc.

Note the case of the color names is ignored.

Note that this is *not permanent*, when you close the vim session, the colour scheme is discarded and reset to the default.

#### Colour change (permanently)

If you want to achieve this permanently, we have to access the `vim` start up file, `.vimrc`. The `.vimrc` file holds the elective runtime settings that get initialized once a vim session begins. We’ll add the color scheme that we want with the help of the `colorscheme` command:

```
:colorscheme white
```

This now configures the default background to be white coloured.

Related sources:

- [Vimdoc highlight syntax](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:highlight)
- [Setting the Vim background colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117526/setting-the-vim-background-colors)
- [Vim background colours](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/vim-background-colors)

Comment: Hi @DialFrost, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, it did not tell me how the background color changes are to be triggered by a mode change, so I awarded another answer, thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: "*it did not tell me how the background color changes are to be triggered by a mode change*", not sure what you mean, but glad it was solved :3 @Jan

Comment: Did my code help though? @Jan, Just want to make sure it actually gives info on how to solve it (other than the mode change ofc) :P

Comment: I needed to know, how pressing `I` or `Esc` can trigger the background color change. Now that I am experimenting with it, it only seems to work as expected in nvim, both vim 8 and 9 color the backgound of characters in lines, but leave whitespace unchanged, which does not look good.
Other than that, it would be interesting to see how to combine @wu hoyt's solution with yours.